# Inserting a value to configure Ajax function upon clicking a link

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I'm trying to set a function that makes an Ajax call, but I must confess I can't understand what's happening when I set the onclick event. I'm trying to make an Ajax call to get fields from a database and display them to the user. The idea is that the users type a Last Name in an input field, and then, depending on the link they click on, the function I'm trying to build displays the results of a query to the database. I handle the query with a switch statement in PHP on the script that the Ajax function calls, but I can't set the variable that handles this behavior on the Javascript code.

I've got the Javascript code like this:

```
var ajaxRequest = ajaxFunction();
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
} return ajaxRequest;
} 

function process() {
id="default";
profesional = document.getElementById('profesional');
dotal = document.getElementById('dot'); 
proyecta = document.getElementById('proy');
proyecta_A = document.getElementById('proy_af');
gastosM = document.getElementById('gastos_med');
autos = document.getElementById('aut');
polifam = document.getElementById('polif');

profesional.onclick=function() {
id="prof";
return id;  
}
dotal.onclick=function() {
id="dotal";
return id;  
}
proyecta.onclick=function() {
id="proyecta";  
return id;
}
proyecta_A.onclick=function() {
id="proyAf";
return id;  
}
gastosM.onclick=function() {
id="gastos_medicos";
return id;  
}
autos.onclick=function() {
id="autos"; 
return id;
}
polifam.onclick=function() {
id="polifam";
return id;  
}   
if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4 || ajaxRequest.readyState==0) {apellido =     encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('query').value)
if (apellido != undefined) {
ajaxRequest.open("GET", 'adminsrc.php?buscarregistro=' +apellido +'&id='+id, true)
ajaxRequest.send("");   
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;
}
}
else setTimeout('process()',1000);
}

function handleServerResponse(){
{
if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4) {

if(ajaxRequest.status==200) {   
respuesta=ajaxRequest.responseXML;
respuestadoc = respuesta.documentElement;
if (apellido != undefined) {
ident = respuesta.getElementsByTagName('identidad')[0];
result = ident.firstChild;
refrescar = respuesta.getElementsByTagName('identidad')[1];
actualizar = refrescar.firstChild;
if(result!=undefined) {
resultado = result.data;
document.getElementById('profesreg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
document.getElementById('dotalreg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
document.getElementById('gmmreg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
document.getElementById('proyectareg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
document.getElementById('proyecta2reg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
document.getElementById('autosreg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
document.getElementById('polifreg').setAttribute('value', resultado);
}
if(actualizar!=undefined) {
actualiza = actualizar.data;
document.getElementById('actual_1').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
document.getElementById('actual_2').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
document.getElementById('actual_3').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
document.getElementById('actual_4').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
document.getElementById('actual_5').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
document.getElementById('actual_6').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
document.getElementById('actual_7').setAttribute('value', actualiza);
}
msje = respuestadoc.firstChild.childNodes[0]; 
if (msje !=undefined) {
mess = msje.data;
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "<h4>"+ mess +"</h4>";
} 
     }
    setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
    else alert ('hubo un problema al conectarse con el servidor: ' +    ajaxRequest.statusText);
}
}
} 

//-->
```

Where the last part is just to set the value of hidden fields in the form so that PHP recognizes those values (they are set to update some fields in the database). 
But I must say I'm pretty stuck with the javascript (I've never been good at it). 
Any suggestions, please?

@Mate The xml file is built like so:

```
<identificacion>
<response>
Se encontró al asegurado con nombre Mara Fernanda Bravo Palomino, número de póliza        27608165, la cual vence el 2003-04-05 y cuyos beneficiarios contratados son Ana Camila Lpez       Bravo
</response>
<identidad>Bravo Palomino</identidad>
<identidad>si</identidad>
</identificacion>
```

And once (a few weeks ago) I already had it working with a function like so:

```
 function process() {
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState==4 || ajaxRequest.readyState==0) {apellido =        encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('query').value)
    if (apellido != undefined) {
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", 'adminsrc.php?buscarregistro=' +apellido, true)
    ajaxRequest.send("");   
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;
    }
    }
    else setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
```

and the function handleServerResponse above; but as you can see I can only extract the text nodes from the xml with that complicated iteration. Surely there's an easier way.

Comment: Have you thought about using a javascript library that will simplify this process? I'd recommend jQuery, which will cut this down a lot, deals with all the cross-browser stuff and has much better documentation.

Comment: Gerardo, veo que te llevas mejor con el español. Tal como menciona @mjec el código se simplifica mucho usando jQuery. Te sirve una solución con jQuery? Te animas a intentarlo?

Comment: @mate Yeah, sure I'd try a solution in Jquery. It's just that being so thick headed to understand Javascript I usually try to do things in plain javascript. I would especially like to know how to capture the click event on the function, since I see there's no way of passing a value to my Ajax Function up until now.

Comment: @Mate Sí, claro que estoy dispuesto a probar una solución con Jquery, es sólo que estando tan bloqueado (aparentemente) para el Javascript, trato de hacer las cosas con Javascript simple. En especial me gustaría saber si es posible hacer esto que me propongo, ya que tengo que capturar dos eventos (uno el cambio de valor del input y otro el click en el vínculo) y pasarlos a la función Ajax.

Comment: @Mate. No sé, algo como hacer un array `arr = ['prof', 'dotal', 'proyecta', 'proyAf', 'gastos_medicos', 'autos', 'polifam'];`
después ejecutar `$('#profesional').bind('click', function ($.grep(arr, function(id) {return id="prof"});`Y en la llamada Ajax `$.get(admin.php?buscarregistro=apellido&id=id);` Por cierto hablo español, pero también suficiente inglés y no tengo preferencia, creo que me comunico bien en ambos. Si crees que mi inglés es malo entonces quizá prefieres que hablemos en español

Comment: @gerardoflores no hay problema, no creo que tu Ingles sea malo. El comentario fue porque la mayor parte del codigo esta en español. Avisame si te sirve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Download jQuery Library and link to te correct path !!

2) I'm a bit blind with html and xml response, but I think you can solve well.

```
        <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function AjaxCall(id) {

                //Obtengo el appelido.
                var apellido = $('#query').val();

                //Armo la url con el querystring
                var urlPhp = 'adminsrc.php?buscarregistro=' + apellido + '&id=' + id;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlPhp,
                    contentType: "charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (xml) {
                        successProcess(xml);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }

            //Proceso el xml si estuvo Ok.
            function successProcess(xml) {
                //Revisar bien el XML devuelto

                var identidades = $(xml).find("identidad");

                result = identidades[0];
                refresh = identidades[1];
                message = $(xml).find('mensaje');

                SetResult(result);
                SetActualizar(refresh);
                SetMsj(message);

            }

            //Seteo el resultado en los valores de los controles.
            function SetResult(resultado) {

                if (result != undefined) {
                    $('#profesreg').val(resultado);
                    $('#dotalreg').val(resultado);
                    $('#gmmreg').val(resultado);
                    $('#proyectareg').val(resultado);
                    $('#proyecta2reg').val(resultado);
                    $('#autosreg').val(resultado);
                    $('#polifreg').val(resultado);
                }
            }

            //Seteo los dato actualizados
            function SetActualizar(actualiza) {
                if (actualiza != undefined) {
                    $('#actual_1').val(actualiza);
                    $('#actual_2').val(actualiza);
                    $('#actual_3').val(actualiza);
                    $('#actual_4').val(actualiza);
                    $('#actual_5').val(actualiza);
                    $('#actual_6').val(actualiza);
                    $('#actual_7').val(actualiza);
                }
            }

            //Muestro el mensaje
            function SetMsj(msje) {

                if (msje != undefined) {
                    $('#res').html("<h4>" + msje + "</h4>");
                }
            }


            //Este evento se dispara cuando carga el documento.
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#profesional').click(function () { AjaxCall('prof') });
                $('#dot').click(function () { AjaxCall('dotal') });
                $('#proy').click(function () { AjaxCall('proyecta') });
                $('#proy_af').click(function () { AjaxCall('proyAf') });
                $('#gastos_med').click(function () { AjaxCall('gastos_medicos') });
                $('#aut').click(function () { AjaxCall('autos') });
                $('#polif').click(function () { AjaxCall('polifam') });

            });


        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: I did this but I get an object (not the data I need) in the console log: `arr = ['prof', 'dotal', 'proyecta', 'proyAf', 'gastos_medicos', 'autos', 'polifam'];
arr = $.grep(arr, function(id) {return (id=='prof')})
$.get('adminsrc.php?buscarregistro=apellido&id=id', function(data) {alert(data)});` So how can I handle the data in the get call (I mean the part where it says `function(data) {//Here the code I need`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give it a try. It seems it should do what I want, and probably my solution with grep was not so straight. I just had a headache about passing a value to a function just as you did on AjaxCall above

Comment: Ok, I hope you find it useful. If that does not fix, edit your question and try to put relevant code  HTML  / XML .

Comment: Sorry for bothering, you see it is this thing with xml, it is far complicated. I copied / pasted the code and it's working ok, but I can't get past the xml node, it just displays [object] like the alert function in my example where I tried with the $.grep() Jquery function. I did some changes to the code you kindly posted and changed to this `dato = $(xml).find('response');    message = dato[0].firstChild;` and I can see I'm getting somewhere because it says now [object Text] and previously [object Element], but I can't get it to work yet

Comment: if when alert(obj) shows [object Text], then try alert(obj.text())

Comment: Thanks, I did `dato = $(xml).find('response');
    message = dato.text();`and now I can read the text node. It seems I should read more carefully the docs in Jquery where it says text() function "Gets the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants". I find it hard to properly use this functions so that they point to the data I need. It now works perfectly

Comment: Congratulations, I'm glad you have been helpful. I guess you can improve this code by reading a bit about jQuery, you have skills!